# How to display local time of the browser in a web app

Tags: language-agnostic

I am writing a web app and I would like to display timestamps on the page in the user's localtime.  There seems to be several ways to do this but it is not obvious what is a good way.

1. Use geolocation from the IP address to get the timezone - This seems like a lot of overhead.
2. Use javascript to finally render the datetime on the page - This seems like a lot of complex client side javascript.
3. Use javascript to get the timezone and locale from the user's preferences and save it in a cookie.  The server can then use this to format the date.  Server side code is nice, but there don't seem to be many good ways to get this for the first page load.
4. Any options for http request headers?  Which ones? How reliable across browsers are they?

Any advice on good ways to implement this?

Comment: Anybody know how StackOverflow does theirs.  It seems to work pretty well.  They don't appear to use Javascript, and they don't appear to send anything to the server on the initial page load that would allow the server to infer the timezone.  Does that just leave GeoIP stuff.

Comment: I ended up implementing this by displaying the relative time instead of an actual timestamp.  i.e. '4 hours ago'.

Answer (score 2):

**Try my [timeago jquery plugin](http://timeago.yarp.com/)**.  It converts UTC timestamps into fuzzy time phrases (e.g. "about 2 hours ago").

You output HTML like this:

```
<abbr class="timeago" title="2008-07-17T09:24:17Z">July 17, 2008</abbr>
```

and the plugin turns that into something like this:

```
<abbr class="timeago" title="July 17, 2008">about a year ago</abbr>
```

by using a little jQuery like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('abbr.timeago').timeago();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

#2 is not very complex, you could even use something like http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-pretty-date/ to display times like on this site ("2 hours ago").

If you absolutely against that, make a guess based on either JS time (seems less error-prone than guessing by IP) and let the user change it.

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes, it's overhead. But you could get it once per session, and then store the offset.

2) Displaying the date with JavaScript isn't too complex. Look at the Date object.

I would make a *guess* at the user's timezone from his computer's local timezone (using JS), and then store that. I would also allow them to change the offset in their preferences of your web app.